# Alert box on the click of radio button of sharepoint list

Tags: list, sharepoint-2010, radio-button

I have requirement where one of the columns is radiobutton called status.There are four choices in the radio button for an example.o choice1. o choice2. o choice3. o choice4.I want to display an alert box( you can not select this option) when manager selects the fourth option ( o choice4).How do i achieve this .Please note radio button is on sharepoint page.I'm a newbie.need some guidance
please help.
Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

you can create a work flow that looks for the fourth option. so in you workflow you could say if option x is selected then send email to .....

Comment: nope:( could some one help me on this...cz m almost at end of the project..n i also could get the value of radio button..i have error in alert box message....My code is here                                                                 Page page = (Page)HttpContext.Current.Handler;//null exception error occurs here

                if (page != null)
                {

                    error = error.Replace("'", "\'");

                    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(page, page.GetType(), "err_msg", "alert('" + error + "');", true);
                   
                }